# Signing key was not provided and could not be derived on google precondition

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to generate a signed url for uploading a file on Google Cloud Platform using java springboot following the instructions provided on:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-code-sample

I'm having a security key with all the permission.
The problem is I'm able to generate a signed url for uploading object with the documentation when I'm runnig the code in local.
But in production I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Signing key was not provided and could not be derived
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:511) ~[guava-29.0-android.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.signUrl(StorageImpl.java:655) ~[google-cloud-storage-1.108.0.jar!/:1.108.0]
```

I searched on Google and according to this resource:

https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/com.google.cloud.storage.Storage/signUrl

changed my code to this:

```
public static URL generateV4PutObjectSignedUrl(String projectId,String bucketName,String objectName)  {
        Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId).build().getService();
        BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(BlobId.of(bucketName, objectName)).build();
        Map<String, String> extensionHeaders = new HashMap<>();
        extensionHeaders.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = storage.signUrl(
                    blobInfo,
                    15,
                    TimeUnit.MINUTES,
                    Storage.SignUrlOption.httpMethod(HttpMethod.PUT),
                    Storage.SignUrlOption.withExtHeaders(extensionHeaders),
                    Storage.SignUrlOption.signWith(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(GOOGLE_API_CREDENTIALS))));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and when I'm trying to upload from the new url is giving me this error:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Message><StringToSign>PUT
```

Comment: It seems your Java code is not fulfilling all the required steps to create the signing key in the documentation [1]. There is a third party doc [2] outlining how to perform this with python that you can base your code off of or convert to. 

[1]:https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/signatures#signing-process

[2]: https://medium.com/google-cloud/gcs-hmac-signedurl-3166b995f237