# GCP Storage - signing key not provided

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, gsutil

Even though I found a similar question here:

[Signing key was not provided and could not be derived on google precondition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63355556/signing-key-was-not-provided-and-could-not-be-derived-on-google-precondition)

This wouldn't lead to a solution to my problem.

I am locally authenticating to Google Storage default service account and I can easily read bucket objects as follows:

```kotlin
    private val storage: Storage = StorageOptions
        .newBuilder()
        .setProjectId(projectId)
        .build()
        .service

    fun read() {
        val blob = storage
            .get(BlobId.of(bucket, object))

        println(String(blob.getContent()))
    }
```

however when I try to generate the signed upload url with:

```kotlin
    fun uploadUrl(objectName: String): String = storage
        .signUrl(
            BlobInfo.newBuilder(BlobId.of(bucketName, objectName)).build(),
            15,
            TimeUnit.MINUTES,
            Storage.SignUrlOption.httpMethod(HttpMethod.PUT),
            Storage.SignUrlOption.withExtHeaders(mapOf("Content-Type" to "application/octet-stream")),
            Storage.SignUrlOption.withV4Signature()
        )
        .toString()
```

I am getting `signing key not provided`.

I find it hard to recognize what actually I am missing. I am authenticated with `gcloud auth application-default login` with a `owner` user and I am normally allowed to perform any gcloud tasks. What is a difference here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To sign something,  you need a private key. With a user credential, you can't, because you only have a refresh token in your environment. However, in a service account key file you have a private key. You can download it and use it, **but I don't like it, for security reason.**

I [wrote an article and I found a workaround in Python](https://medium.com/google-cloud/service-account-credentials-api-a-solution-to-different-issues-dc7434037115). I built a similar hack in Java (Sorry, I'm not kotlin dev! But I'm sure it's each to convert!).

```
Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

Credentials credentialsToSIgn = storage.getOptions().getCredentials();
if (credentialsToSIgn instanceof UserCredentials) {
  credentialsToSIgn = ImpersonatedCredentials.create(
    (GoogleCredentials) credentialsToSIgn,
    "SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL",
    Collections.EMPTY_LIST, 
    Collections.EMPTY_LIST, 
    3600);
}
System.out.println(
  storage.signUrl(
    BlobInfo.newBuilder(BlobId.of(bucketName, objectName)).build(),
    15,
    TimeUnit.MINUTES,
    Storage.SignUrlOption.httpMethod(HttpMethod.PUT),
    Storage.SignUrlOption.withExtHeaders(mapOf("Content-Type" to "application/octet-stream")),
    Storage.SignUrlOption.withV4Signature()
    Storage.SignUrlOption.signWith((ServiceAccountSigner) credentialsToSIgn)
  )
);
```

*The ImpersonatedCredentials is only here to use the [sign method in the class](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java/blob/3b50627ae745ca92547530278e1781da8c46b7f7/oauth2_http/java/com/google/auth/oauth2/ImpersonatedCredentials.java#L195-L202). This sign method uses the [IAMUtils.sign](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java/blob/3b50627ae745ca92547530278e1781da8c46b7f7/oauth2_http/java/com/google/auth/oauth2/IamUtils.java#L74) method which [call the Service Account Credential API](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java/blob/3b50627ae745ca92547530278e1781da8c46b7f7/oauth2_http/java/com/google/auth/oauth2/IamUtils.java#L99), as described in my article*.

It's not a nice hack, but it works. You can put the service account email in parameter, and omit it outside your local environment to sure to not perform wrong things elsewhere.

Comment: `StorageException: class com.google.auth.oauth2.UserCredentials cannot be cast to class com.google.auth.ServiceAccountSigner (com.google.auth.oauth2.UserCredentials and com.google.auth.ServiceAccountSigner are in unnamed module of loader 'app') `

Comment: This hack no longer seems to work. 400 Error

Comment: Error 400 is an API call error, with bad parameters. Are you sure of the different values? Are you in the acceptable bounds for each of them?